# :active keep animation even when we release the mouse button

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

css code:

```
.container .elements:active{
    animation: click 1s;
}
/*animations */

@keyframes click{
    0%{border:solid;
        border-color: white;
        height: 100%;}
    50%{border:solid;
        border-color: blue;
        height:50%}
    100%{border:solid;
        border-color: white;
        height: 100%;}
}
```

When i do this, it doesn't show the entire 1s of animation if i release the mouse button, how can i do to show the entire animation if the use click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fun way is using checkbox states;

```
<div class='container'>
    <input id='check' type='checkbox'/>
    <label class='elements' for='check'>aaaa</label>
</div>
```

with css;

```
#check:checked~ .elements{animation: click 1s;}
input{display: none;}
```

This is really easy but not semantically correct.

## **The real answer:**

html;

```
<div class='container'>
    <div id='element1' onclick='ani()'>Element</div>
</div>
```

javascript;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ani(){
        document.getElementById('element1').className ='animateclass';
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.getElementById("element1").classList.remove("animateclass");
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

css;

```
.animateclass{animation: click 1s;}
```